# How can I cut curves drawn by `geom_curve` in order they don't overlap labels plotted by `geom_text` in `ggplot2`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `df` containing elements of type `var` and `link`. I want to plot the elements `var` as text label using `geom_text` and the `links` as arrows using `geom_curve`. The problem is, that the `links` overplot the labels whereas I want them to start and stop just beside the labels.

---

What I have:

```
  type   x    y                    label from_x from_y to_x to_y
1 link  NA   NA                     <NA>    608   -229  460 -276
2 link  NA   NA                     <NA>    428   -274  570 -226
3  var 610 -226 accomplishments per week    608   -229  460   NA
4  var 426 -276    hours worked per week    428   -274  570   NA
```

When I plot it it looks as follows:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = label)) + geom_curve(aes(x = 
from_x,y = from_y,xend = to_x, yend = to_y), curvature = -.3, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc")), color = "red")
```

[image]

---

What I expect is:

[image]

**How can I achieve this?**

---

Here is my `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("link", 
"var"), class = "factor"), x = c(NA, NA, 610, 426), y = c(NA, 
NA, -226, -276), label = c(NA, NA, "accomplishments per week", 
"hours worked per week"), from_x = c(610, 426, NA, NA), from_y = c(-226, 
-276, NA, NA), to_x = c(426, 610, NA, NA), to_y = c(-276, -226, 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("type", "x", "y", "label", "from_x", "from_y", 
"to_x", "to_y"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is the *manual* tweak I did to plot my expected output:

```
df$from_x <- c(608, 428)
df$from_y <- c(-229, -274)
df$to_x <- c(460, 570)

ggplot(df) + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = label)) + geom_curve(aes(x = from_x,y = from_y,xend = to_x, yend = to_y), curvature = -.3, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc")), color = "red")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Calculate an appropriate offset for the `to_x` and `from_y`.
2. Change the order of your geoms so `geom_text` is rendered last (i.e. top) in the stack

```
df <-
  df %>%
  mutate(
    to_xoffset = if_else(to_y > -250, to_x - 25, NA_real_),
    to_xoffset = if_else(to_y < -250, to_x + 25, to_xoffset),

    from_yoffset = if_else(from_x < 525, from_y + 2, NA_real_),
    from_yoffset = if_else(from_x > 525, from_y - 2, from_yoffset)
  )

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_curve(aes(x = from_x,y = from_yoffset ,xend = to_xoffset, yend = to_y), curvature = -.3, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc")), color = "red") +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = label))
```

Comment: @symbolrush Added an x and yoffset

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. This is a first step, +1 for the nice calculation using `NA_real_`. Didn't know that existed. :) On the other side this is still not fully satisfactory, since the offset is independently from the label width and height, whereas in my real data labels can be rather small and very long and offsets should be dynamic, according to label dimensions.

Comment: Calculating a dynamic offset is challenging with `ggplot2` because the w/h of the labels is going to be dependent on things like font, font size, font weight, etc. that are only calculated when the `ggplot()` function is called. I.e. AFAIK it's not possible to calculate the dimensions of the label, apply an appropriate offset, then plug that back into `geom_curve()`.

Comment: One approach could be to call a dummy plot object with just the text labels (e.g. `dummy <- ggplot(df) + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = label))`) and explore the `dummy` object for information about the rendered labels. You could then use these as inputs for your offset, but I don't know enough about `ggplot2`'s internals to do that! Could there be a more appropriate tool for this like [`TikZ`](http://www.texample.net/tikz/)?